# PHP rename a uploaded file (image)

Tags: php, html

I want to rename the uploaded files. The names should be a random unique number.

Here is my upload script:

```html
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

        if(!($check == false)){
            if(file_exists($target_file)){
                $meldung = "Der Bildname exestiert bereits.";
            }
            if($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5242880){ /*Bytes*/
                $meldung = $meldung . "Das Bild ist zu groß.";
            }
            if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "JPG" && $imageFileType != "PNG" && $imageFileType != "JPEG") {
                $meldung = $meldung . "Ungültiges Format.";
            }

            if(!(empty($meldung))){
                $meldung = $meldung . "Die Datei wurde nicht hochgeladen.";
            }
            else{
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                    $picturename = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
                    $pictureheightwidth = $check[3];
                    $picturepath = $target_file;
        
                    $eintrag = "INSERT INTO bilder (bild_name, bild_werte, bild_pfad) VALUES ('$picturename', '$pictureheightwidth', '$picturepath')";
                    $eintragen = mysqli_query($db, $eintrag);    
        
                    $meldung = "Das Bild wurde erfolgreich hochgeladen";
                }
                else{
                    $meldung = $meldung . "Fehler beim hochladen des Bildes.";
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "Die Datei ist kein Bild.";
        }
    }
    echo $meldung;
?> 

<form action="index.php?content=upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Hochladen" class="button-submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: `$picturename=rand();`

Comment: My fault. I want to change the real picture name. In the folder "Upload", because i get everytime errors because one is two times in the folder. Not the variable my fault sorry

Comment: Many ways to do this. Look under **Related** over to the right >>>

Comment: UNIX timestamp in conjunction with any type of random function will work.

Comment: The attempt to find out the type of a file (the image format) by looking at the file name extension is not very reliable. Anyone can fake that anytime. So what is the point in looking at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can give you a clue on how to rename your file

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `uniqid()` function:

```
$pictureame = uniqid(rand(), true);
```

It generates such a "random" id but, at the same time, also takes care that that unique name is not yet used by another file. Without that you would risk collisions. Not very likely at first sight, but that is just a question of scaling :-)

Take a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: My fault. I want to change the real picture name. In the folder "Upload", because i get everytime errors because one is two times in the folder. Not the variable my fault sorry

Comment: I don't see the problem here: you use the generated file name the final name under which you finally save the image with the `move_uploaded_file()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answe but `if(file_exists($target_file)){
                $meldung = "Der Bildname exestiert bereits.";
            }` here i get an error

Comment: Sure, because currently you do _not_ use a randomized filename at exactly that position.

Comment: = i dont have to change the file name inside the folder? Only the names inside the database?

Comment: What? No, I did not say so. You use `move_uploaded_file()` to move the uploaded file to its final position. When calling that function you specify the path and name under which to save it. For that you use a randomized file name constructed with help of mentioned `uniqid()` function. Then you can also register the moved file inside your database if you like.

Comment: Now i understood it. `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]` I have to change the `"tmp_name"` to my variable with the number?

Comment: No. `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]` is the name of the file under which the file has been _temporarily_ stored by the http server for you to pick it up in your script. That is temporary and you have to move it to a final location. That is what you do with the `move_uploaded_file()` function. In that move operation you can "rename" it on the fly, since you can specify the file under which the file will be finally saved. I suggest you start reading a bit about the commands you use in your script. The PHP documentation is only a few keystrokes away and very precise and easy to understand.